# How can I insert automatic number to field id in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I insert automatic number to field id in mysql?  I have `idmember` that is primary key already
This is code that I have tried, please correct it

```
UPDATE member SET id = Row_number()over ORDER BY idmember

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'over order by idmember' at line 1
```

Comment: There are no analytic functions avialable in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE member (id INT PRIMARY KEY, idmember INT);
INSERT INTO member (id, idmember) VALUES (10, 10), (11, 20), (12, 42);

SELECT * FROM member;
+----+----------+
| id | idmember |
+----+----------+
| 10 |       10 |
| 11 |       20 |
| 12 |       42 |
+----+----------+

SET @i := 0;
UPDATE member SET id = @i:=@i+1 ORDER BY idmember;

SELECT * FROM member;
+----+----------+
| id | idmember |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       10 |
|  2 |       20 |
|  3 |       42 |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your ID field to auto_increment from table structure, then it will increment automatically

Comment: I try that but it not allow Because I have primary key akready